# Apply loaded Drawable from resources to more Views

Tags: java, android, resources, drawable

I have a drawable, which is clickable. I'm loading it from resources to var:

```
Drawable mDrawable;
mDrawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.clickable_d, null);
```

It is "clickable drawable", so it has different states images when it is clicked and when not.

clickable_d:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_pressed="true"
              android:drawable="@drawable/clickable_d_pressed" /> 
        <item android:state_focused="true"
              android:drawable="@drawable/clickable_d_pressed" />  
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/clickable_d_not_pressed" />  
</selector>
```

I want to apply this to 20 `ImageButton`s, so I tried setting my loaded *mDrawable* to all of them. But pressed state is working just for the last one (20th, because I'm doing this in fori cycle) - every time I press any `ImageButton`, only the last one became "pressed".

If I set freshly loaded resource (`getResources(), R.drawabl..`) to every ImageView, it is working fine. However, loading 20times same drawable isn't best for optimalization...

How do I load mDrawable just once, set it for all ImageViews and make their changing states work?

Comment: `"oading 20times same drawable isn't best for optimalization..."`, yes it is, you have to call `ResourcesCompat.getDrawable` 20 times

Comment: So you mean there's no other way?

Comment: no, you have to call `ResourcesCompat.getDrawable` 20 times

Comment: okay, thanks for clarification.

Comment: is this just a typo? `R.drawable.clickable_d` ? In your selector you have two other resources referenced as in your drawable load...

Comment: `clickable_d` is a selector drawable xml, `clickable_d_pressed` and `clickable_d_not_pressed` are images in resources.